# How do I repair a cyclic redundancy check data error?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

A client of ours is trying to copy his database, but get's this Windows error:

> **Error Message:** Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
>
> **Explanation**: The operating system cannot read or write the data
>   correctly.
>
> **User Action:** If the error occurred on a hard disk, retry the command. If
>   the error occurs again, try running
>   some disk utilities to correct the
>   problem. If the error occurred on a
>   floppy disk, insert a formatted floppy
>   disk or the backup floppy disk, and
>   retry the command.

Is there anything he can do to fix his hard drive? Something like check disk?

Comment: They ended up just repairing the file itself, which is probably a simple form of check disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates a serious disk/data error.
They could try forcing the [windows disk check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315265).

Try to boot in **Safe Mode** (usually with the `F8` key), and select full disk check (scandisk).

Check to see if the database has any recovery options for disk-errors.

If they have a backup, it would be a good time to get it out now.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Spinrite (not free)

[SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm).

[image: Spinrite]

It's a tool that will scrub your hard disk, bypassing all the built-in mechanisms to repair sectors on the disk. It can fix many a hard disk that would otherwise be toast because of a few bad sectors here and there, and will in most cases help recover files.

Comment: Looks good, too bad it's a student having the problem, not sure if they will buy ANYTHING... Good suggestion anyway

Comment: Yeah, I know. But spinrite does really impressive work, and I don't know any other tool that can save you from a CRC error :(

Comment: Well I might get it for myself, so I'm still thankful for the answer!

Comment: Don't forget that spinrite is "Satisfaction Guaranteed", so if it can't help you, you can ask for a full refund.